# CLion break points are skipped

Tags: debugging, clion

I have a c++ application with makefile and would like to use Clion debugger to follow data. Is it possible to set break points to do that? What would be the configuration? For the moment I set up:
configuration type: Native application, the program works fine but none of the break points stops the flow